# css styling not working properly on the div tag created on the fly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am working on the following code below which displays a grid and display more grids on click.

Right now, when a new grid is created, as seen in the running demo below, the new grid gets created but the problem is that it's right below the original grid. I want to have some space between the original grid and the newly created grid. Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9wsqK/930/) for the below code for reference

The reason some columns are showing red is because I have the following style property set here in the code:

```
 $("<div />")
    .append($("<div />", { id: "grid" + id ,style:"color: red" }))
```

However, if I try to apply the following css

```
 $("<div />")
    .append($("<div />", { id: "grid" + id ,style:"50px 10px 20px 30px" }))
```

Nothing happens. I have a feeling that I am applying it at wrong place. Please let me know where exactly it should be applied.

```js
  var source =
                {
                    localdata: [
                        ["https://www.samplelink.com", "Maria Anders", "Sales Representative", "Obere Str. 57", "Berlin", "Germany"],
                        ["https://www.samplelink.com", "Ana Trujillo", "Owner", "Avda. de la Constitucin 2222", "Mxico D.F.", "Mexico"],
                        ["https://www.samplelink.com", "Antonio Moreno", "Owner", "Mataderos 2312", "Mxico D.F.", "Mexico"],
                        ["https://www.samplelink.com", "Thomas Hardy", "Sales Representative", "120 Hanover Sq.", "London", "UK"],
                        ["https://www.samplelink.com", "Christina Berglund", "Order Administrator", "Berguvsvgen 8", "Lule", "Sweden"],
                        ["https://www.samplelink.com", "Hanna Moos", "Sales Representative", "Forsterstr. 57", "Mannheim", "Germany"],
                        ["https://www.samplelink.com", "Frdrique Citeaux", "Marketing Manager", "24, place Klber", "Strasbourg", "France"],
                        ["https://www.samplelink.com", "Martn Sommer", "Owner", "C\/ Araquil, 67", "Madrid", "Spain"],
                        ["https://www.samplelink.com", "Laurence Lebihan", "Owner", "12, rue des Bouchers", "Marseille", "France"],
                        ["https://www.samplelink.com", "Elizabeth Lincoln", "Accounting Manager", "23 Tsawassen Blvd.", "Tsawassen", "Canada"],
                        ["https://www.samplelink.com", "Victoria Ashworth", "Sales Representative", "Fauntleroy Circus", "London", "UK"],
                        ["https://www.samplelink.com", "Patricio Simpson", "Sales Agent", "Cerrito 333", "Buenos Aires", "Argentina"],
                        ["https://www.samplelink.com", "Francisco Chang", "Marketing Manager", "Sierras de Granada 9993", "Mxico D.F.", "Mexico"],
                        ["https://www.samplelink.com", "Yang Wang", "Owner", "Hauptstr. 29", "Bern", "Switzerland"],
                        ["https://www.samplelink.com", "Pedro Afonso", "Sales Associate", "Av. dos Lusadas, 23", "Sao Paulo", "Brazil"],
                        ["https://www.samplelink.com", "Elizabeth Brown", "Sales Representative", "Berkeley Gardens 12 Brewery", "London", "UK"],
                        ["https://www.samplelink.com", "Sven Ottlieb", "Order Administrator", "Walserweg 21", "Aachen", "Germany"],
                        ["https://www.samplelink.com", "Janine Labrune", "Owner", "67, rue des Cinquante Otages", "Nantes", "France"],
                        ["https://www.samplelink.com", "Ann Devon", "Sales Agent", "35 King George", "London", "UK"],
                        ["https://www.samplelink.com", "Roland Mendel", "Sales Manager", "Kirchgasse 6", "Graz", "Austria"]
                    ],
                    datafields: [
                        { name: 'link', type: 'string', map: '0' },
                        { name: 'ContactName', type: 'string', map: '1' },
                        { name: 'Title', type: 'string', map: '2' },
                        { name: 'Address', type: 'string', map: '3' },
                        { name: 'City', type: 'string', map: '4' },
                        { name: 'Country', type: 'string', map: '5' }
                    ],
                    datatype: "array"
                };
            var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);

            var cellsrenderer = function (row, column, value) {
                return `<div style="color: blue">${value}</div>`;
            };

            $("#grid").jqxGrid(
                {
                    width: 800,
                    source: dataAdapter,
                    columnsresize: true,
                    sortable: true,
                    columns: [
                        { text: 'Link', datafield: 'link', width: 200, cellsrenderer: cellsrenderer },
                        { text: 'Contact Name', datafield: 'ContactName', width: 150 },
                        { text: 'Contact Title', datafield: 'Title', width: 100 },
                        { text: 'Address', datafield: 'Address', width: 100 },
                        { text: 'City', datafield: 'City', width: 100 },
                        { text: 'Country', datafield: 'Country' }
                    ]
                });

            var id = 1;

            $("#grid").on("rowselect", function (e) {

                $("<div />")
                    .append($("<div />", { id: "grid" + id ,style:"color: red" }))
                    .append($("<div />", { id: "button" + id }))
                    .appendTo(document.body);
               

                $("#grid" + id).jqxGrid({
                    source: dataAdapter, columns: [
                        { text: 'Link', datafield: 'link', width: 200, cellsrenderer: cellsrenderer },
                        { text: 'Contact Name', datafield: 'ContactName', width: 150 },
                        { text: 'Contact Title', datafield: 'Title', width: 100 },
                        { text: 'Address', datafield: 'Address', width: 100 },
                        { text: 'City', datafield: 'City', width: 100 },
                        { text: 'Country', datafield: 'Country' }
                    ]
                });

                $("#grid" + id).on('rowselect', function () {
                    $("<div />")
                        .append($("<div />", { id: "grid" + id }))
                        .append($("<div />", { id: "button" + id }))
                        .appendTo(document.body);


                    $("#grid" + id).jqxGrid({
                        source: dataAdapter, columns: [
                            { text: 'Link', datafield: 'link', width: 200, cellsrenderer: cellsrenderer },
                            { text: 'Contact Name', datafield: 'ContactName', width: 150 },
                            { text: 'Contact Title', datafield: 'Title', width: 100 },
                            { text: 'Address', datafield: 'Address', width: 100 },
                            { text: 'City', datafield: 'City', width: 100 },
                            { text: 'Country', datafield: 'Country' }
                        ]
                    });

                    $("#grid" + id).on('rowselect', function () {

                    });

                    $("#button" + id).jqxButton({ value: 'Export Grid ' + id });

                    let currentId = id;
                    $("#button" + currentId).on('click', function () {
                        //console.log('clickin ', currentId)
                        $("#grid" + currentId).jqxGrid('exportdata', 'pdf', 'jqxGrid' + currentId);
                    });

                    id++;
                });

                $("#button" + id).jqxButton({ value: 'Export Grid ' + id });

                let currentId = id;
                $("#button" + currentId).on('click', function () {
                    //console.log('click ', currentId)
                    $("#grid" + currentId).jqxGrid('exportdata', 'pdf', 'jqxGrid' + currentId);
                });

                id++;
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://jqwidgets.com/public/jqwidgets/jqx-all.js"></script>
<link href="https://jqwidgets.com/public/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="grid">
        </div>
```

Comment: Try something like style:"**margin:** 50px 10px 20px 30px". Or padding...

Comment: Yes, `style:"margin: 50px 10px 20px 30px` works fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same way you are using a property before the value in style here :

```
 $("<div />")
    .append($("<div />", { id: "grid" + id ,style:"color: red" }))
```

You need to apply a property before values here :

```
 $("<div />")
    .append($("<div />", { id: "grid" + id ,style:"50px 10px 20px 30px" }))
```

Something like :

```
 $("<div />")
    .append($("<div />", { id: "grid" + id ,style:"padding: 50px 10px 20px 30px" }))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add margin or padding in the style attribute

```
$("<div />")
.append($("<div />", { id: "grid" + id ,style:"50px 10px 20px 30px" }))
```

The way you specified style will get compiled wrong with CSS. Update the same with following code snippet.

```
$("<div />")
.append($("<div />", { id: "grid" + id ,style:"padding:50px 10px 20px 30px" }))
```

Based on your preference you can even add margin instead of padding.